# obj-c method with multiple args in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode

I am working on an appcelerator module in Xcode, written in obj-c.

I have a method that takes multiple args, like the one below:

```
 -(void)useThis:(NSString*)this withThat:(NSString*)that{}
```

In appcelerator, how would I call that method? What is the proper syntax?

```
 var foo = require("module");
 foo.useThiswithThat("this","that");
```

doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that works or not. (I think the current approach won't work).

When I developed modules for Titanium, in such a situation I used like:

```
-(void)useThisWithThat:(NSArray *)thisThat
{
    // Array contains both this and that
}
```

And called like:

```
foo.useThiswithThat(["this","that"]);
```